# Convert part of a string to int in one command in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I have a long string where I know the location of start and end of an integer. I want to extract the integer and store it in a variable. This is how I can do it now.

```
//MY_STRING, INT_START, INT_END are the string, start 
//position of the int and end position respectively.
char * temp;
strncpy(temp, MY_STRING+INT_START, INT_END-INT_START);
int n = atoi(temp);
```

The question is can I do this in one line, instead of using a temp string?

Comment: Why "one line"..specifically?

Comment: Maybe atoi can automatically detect the end of a number: atoi(MY_STRING+INT_START). In online GDB it works.

Comment: Be aware that `strncpy` is not a safer version of `strcpy`. You may end up with a non NUL terminated string. Read carefully the [strncpy documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)

Comment: If you really need a one liner that does error checking, you can simply write your own parsing functions, and even differentiate different types and formats (`parse_u32`, `parse_float`, `parse_hex16`). Then you'll have a one liner which does what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I do this in one line, instead of using a temp string?

Use `sscanf()` for a quick dirty no-`temp`.

```
int n;
//                                  v--- scan width limit
//                                  |    v---------------v
if (sscanf(MY_STRING + INT_START, "%*d", INT_END-INT_START, &n) == 1) {
  puts("Success");
}
```

Better code would consider trouble with overflow.

---

OP's code is no good as `temp` is not certain to point to a *string*.  It may lack a *null character*.

```
strncpy(temp, MY_STRING+INT_START, INT_END-INT_START);
int n = atoi(temp); // bad
```

Comment: Well, but this is 4 lines *scnr*

Comment: @moooeeeep but I guess the requirement was to avoid the temp string...so this should be okay.

Comment: @moooeeeep At least the _conversion_ happens in one line/command.

Comment: INT_END and INT_START are supposed to check for null character. They come from a token generator.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do it in one line and the number of source code lines is most often an irrelevant metric. The only things that matter are safety, readability and performance. `strncpy` and `atoi` are both unsafe functions.

The correct way to do this is however quite similar:

```
int strn_to_int (const char* src, size_t n)
{
  char str [LARGE_ENOUGH];
  memcpy(str, src, n);
  str[n] = '\0';
  return strtol(str, NULL, 10);
}

...

int n = strn_to_int (&MY_STRING[INT_START], INT_END-INT_START);
```